# How to use <rosparam> to change values from dwa_local_planner_params.yaml?

Tags: roslaunch, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a launch file that includes turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch and I want to set the values of certain move_base parameters.  gmapping_demo.launch traces to move_base.launch.xml which traces to turtlebot_navigation/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml.

If I can "rosparam get" the parameter that I want to change, how can I set that parameter inside of my launch file that I created?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230448/how-to-use-%3Crosparam%3E-to-change-values-from-dwa_local_planner_params.yaml?/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out.  Since these parameters are global parameters, you can just use "rosparam list" to find the parameter you want to change, (in my case it was /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_x), and then add:

```
<param name="/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_x"  value="0.1"/>
```

to your launch file.

---

Originally posted by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) with karma: 354 on 2016-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0